# How to make extension to autocomplete code snippets for visual studio code ? Where to start from?

Tags: scripting, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am interested in creating some autocomplete extension for VS Code like the html ones which auto-completes the word into some complete code snippet . I want to do the same but for a different language , could be for personal use as well. I am assuming that language does not matter here . So if anyone can direct me to the correct path for how to do that , i would be very thankful . 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use User Snippets for that check this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Thanks , i should have looked at the VSCode site first . 
But thanks for the response and a really helpful link .